# importing database from phpmyadmin to linode

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin, linode

I've been searching the web for a solution for a while now & just can't seem to get it with what i've found online.  I've exported my phpMyAdmin database & uploaded it to my Linode so its now there ( /home/user_name/public/www.sitename.com/public/phpmyadmindatabase.sql )

So now in the terminal i'm entering the following:

```
mysql -u root -pMyPassword database_name < ~/public/sitename.com/public/phpmyadmindatabase.sql
```

and I get the following:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'database_name'
```

Now I'm wondering if i need to create 'database_name' first, but I'm following Linode's own start up guides:

http://library.linode.com/hosting-website#sph_installing-mysql

and they say right at the section "Creating a Database"...(If you already have a database you'd like to import...skip to "importing a database").  So i have been assuming i shouldn't be creating a database since it told me to skip it.

Any & all help would be greatly appreciated...

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake...just needed to create the new DB manually or make sure phpmyadmin is creating the DB in mysql when its added to the Linode.

On another note - Linode has pretty great customer support (guess that would be the first place to go).